# Is there a way to have a CGRect adapts its size from the parent view?

Tags: swift, appkit, cgrect

I'm working on a Mac app where I'm displaying mathtext with [iosMath](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath) following several answer's and turorials I am using a CGRect as a Frame for that View.

```
import AppKit
import iosMath

class Latex: NSViewController {

    var latexstring: String!
    let latexlabel = MTMathUILabel()

    override func loadView() {
    
        self.view = NSView()
        self.view.backgroundColor = NSColor.cyan
    
    
        self.view.addSubview(latexlabel)
        latexlabel.backgroundColor = NSColor.black
        latexlabel.textColor = .white
        latexlabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 100)
        latexlabel.latex = latexstring
        latexlabel.textAlignment = .center
    }
}
```

Now that puts me with the frame in the bottom left corner, how can I now size the frame to fit the parent view?

I thought it would be as easy a getting the parent size with `self.view.frame.size` and respectively `.height`or `.width`
but that didnt do the trick ...

What I actually want to achieve is having the View centered in its parent without contraints for the input

glad about any tips, thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "without contraints for the input"? Without `NSConstraint`s? Which input?

Comment: Well the view is getting a String containing Latex Code and I want to be able to tile multiple of those back to back and right now I have the options: 1. risk of the content overflowing the rect not displaying eveything or 2. a big gap between multiple instances

Comment: See [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853).